# How to decrypt by Python for AES encrypt by PHP

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I got AES encrypted hex text by PHP. This is below:

The Code is below:

```
<?php
$str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$method = "aes-256-cbc";
$key = 'pqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijAB';
$iv = 'DEFGHTABCIESPQXO';
echo bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($str, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
echo "\n";
?>
```

`2324ab5ec7a901247bf01b08bd1956688843dad5a8e15106ca3a5b9258918527`

I made Python script:

```
import binascii
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
key = "pqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijAB"
iv = "DEFGHTABCIESPQXO"

encrypted = "2324ab5ec7a901247bf01b08bd1956688843dad5a8e15106ca3a5b9258918527"

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decrypted = cipher.decrypt(binascii.unhexlify(encrypted))
print(decrypted)
```

I got this, It's not same string with "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",:

`b' \xea\xbc\x13\x98!xw\x0c,\xac6\xeb\x1c\x14\\Z\x0b\x0fTY\xbe\x0b^W\xcem\xa4\x9ea\xde\x1b'`

I got an error

```
decrypted.decode('utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: invalid continuation byte
```

I want to resolve for this Python Script.

Comment: You are trying to use a 192-bit key with 256-bit AES, I'd correct that before doing anything else.

Comment: Very thank you!! I can decrypt by 32bit key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified PHP code

`$key = 'pqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijAB12345678';`

I got new encrypted string is:

`4a3d8b7449fb45c521b04314382670e9c4255682cde4fda51d715a3631718ccb`

Then, I modified Python code for key,

`key = "pqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijAB12345678"`

I received the below.

`b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06'`

I added to remove

`unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]
unpad(decrypted).decode('utf-8')`

I resolved!!

Comment: `decrypted = cipher.decrypt(binascii.unhexlify(encrypted)).strip()` would be suffice (No need to use `unpad`).